# Can I use a ForeignKey in __unicode__ return?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following classes: Ingredients, Recipe and RecipeContent...

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    qty_on_stock = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class RecipeContent(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    ingredients = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    qty_used = models.IntegerField()
```

but for __unicode__() in RecipeContent I would like to use the Recipe name to which this RecipeContent belongs to... is there a way to do it?

Comment: Just a note about style, I'd recommend that you don't pluralize your ForeignKey field names since they can only point to one record at a time.  I'm referring to your ingredients field under RecipeContent.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
class RecipeContent(models.Model):
  ...
  def __unicode__(self):
    # You can access ForeignKey properties through the field name!
    return self.recipe.name
```

Comment: sigh... it was so simple! shows what a noob I am...

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Using Django 1.6. I get: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'. Method: def __unicode__(self):  
            return self.instrument.name. And: class Instrument(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200). And where I call "unicode":    instrument = models.ForeignKey(Instrument,null=True,blank=True)

Comment: I got this too. I'm pretty this occurs when some instances have this while some don't. I ended up having to flush.

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about the name part of the Recipe, you can do:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class RecipeContent(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.recipe)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can (as bishanty points), but be prepared for situation when `__unicode__()` is called but FK is not set yet. I came into this few times.

Comment: true... but maybe i can deal with that using something along the lines of "if self.recipe.name: return self.recipe.name"?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 there is no `__unicode__`, you need to use `__str__` instead.

```
    class RecipeContent(models.Model):
        ...
        def __str__(self):
            return self.recipe.name
```